# Add app shortcuts to top XFCE4 panel through the terminal

Tags: xfce

Is there a way to add app shortcuts to the top panel through the terminal? I need to add the existing app to the panel using only the terminal command and without opening any windows.

[Like](https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=5b630d99688ce2fb24976db558eafe45)